# kendo grid frozen navigation

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, frozen-columns

I've a kendo grid with Navigatable option, and the grid navigation is working fine when I press Tab. But when I make some columns in grid as locked (frozen columns), the grid navigation is not working as expected. The navigation is working for only frozen columns and then for unfrozen columns.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProcessModel>()
      ...
  .Navigatable())
```

[dojo.telerik.com/@joeTopazz/ODEbA](http://dojo.telerik.com/@joeTopazz/ODEbA)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The following page works normally, what is different in your case?

http://dojo.telerik.com/eLUCU

Comment: The problem is occurring when the edit mode is "editable: "inline" and when we bring the Edit, Delete command buttons to first column and make it locked. Also make Product and UnitPrice locked too. Now when we click Edit button and when we tab from Product column, it is acting weird. http://dojo.telerik.com/@joeTopazz/ODEbA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Grid has its keyboard navigation enabled, tabbing inside the widget is managed **only** when `incell` editing is used. In your example with `inline` editing, tabbing is managed by the browser and the observed behavior is expected due to the separate tables used for the locked and unlocked columns.

To achieve the desired tabbing order, use `incell` editing, or set a `tabindex` for all buttons and inputs from the edit row in the Grid's `edit` event:

http://dojo.telerik.com/EVuNe

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    navigatable: true,
    editable: "inline",
    edit: function(e){
        e.sender.wrapper
            .find(".k-grid-edit-row input,.k-grid-edit-row a")
            .attr("tabindex", 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Dimodi, Thank you for the quick reply. When I access the dojo telerik, it is saying "Failed to load snippet." . Can you please recheck?

Comment: This is a temporary problem with the Dojo playground, you can try again and it will load. I also edited my reply to include the code that you need.